# "Duplicate" serial device - read/write from 2 processes

Tags: linux, serial-port, socat, modbus

I have a serial/rs485 converter to read/write from a Modbus device.
I have the need to be able to read and write from 2 process.

How can i "copy" the real device `/dev/ttyUSB0` to specify in my programm the virtual devices as i would with the physcial one? E.g. (`/dev/ttyUSB0-1`, `/dev/ttyUSB-2`).

I have tried it with socat:

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0-1 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0-2 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0
```

But no program gets a response.
Not sure if the request even reaches the real serial device.

Comment: You would surely be better off with a 3rd process to exclusively handle the serial communications. There are well-defined interfaces provided by Linux for inter-process communication. There's nothing for sharing a serial port, because that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

With the second PTY addresses in your commands you create new ptys, this is probably not what you want to do, instead you should access the existing pty like a file. This command should forward data between the physical and one virtual device:

```
  socat -d -d PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0-1 FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0
```

Now for the copying: Socat 1.8 package provides a shell script that should help. Use these three commands, e.g. in different terminal windows:

```
socat-mux.sh -d -d UNIX-L:/tmp/ttyUSB0,fork FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0
socat        -d -d PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0-1 UNIX:/tmp/ttyUSB0
socat        -d -d PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyUSB0-2 UNIX:/tmp/ttyUSB0
```

The first command opens the tty and starts a listener; an arbitrary number of clients may connect, and data will be forwarded from clients to the tty and from the tty to the clients (internally this script uses UDP broadcasts on the loopback interface to do the copying). The socat-mux listener can provide only one passive (listening) address and must be forking, therefore we cannot use pty here but need the trick with a UNIX domain socket.
The second and third commands wrap between the pseudo terminals and the UNIX socket. /dev/ttyUSB0-1 and /dev/ttyUSB0-2 can now be accessed as you wished.

Comment: I have no `socat-mux.sh`, because i have socat `1.7.4.1` installed on Rasbian 11. (No update available) Is there a alternative? Or where can i find the script contents to create it manually?

Comment: There is a temporary download location in http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/download/socat-mux.sh; make it executable and move it to /usr/bin